# Sharing runtime variables between files

Tags: c++, scope, session-variables

I have a project with a few files that all include the header `global.hpp`. Those files want to share and update information that is relevant for the whole program during runtime (that data is gathered progressively during the program runs but the fields of data are known at compile-time). Now my idea was to use a struct like this:

#### global.hpp

```
#include <string>

#ifndef _GLOBAL_SESSION_STRUCT
#define _GLOBAL_SESSION_STRUCT

struct session_struct {
    std::string username;
    std::string password;
    std::string hostname;
    unsigned short port;
    // more data fields as needed
};

#endif

extern struct session_struct session;
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include "global.hpp"

struct session_struct session;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    session.username = "user";
    session.password = "secret";
    session.hostname = "example.com";
    session.port = 80;

    // other stuff, etc

    return 0;
}
```

Now every file that includes `global.hpp` can just read & write the fields of the `session` struct and easily share information.

Is this the correct way to do this?

**NOTE**: For this specific project no threading is used. But please (for future projects and other people reading) clarify in your answer how this (or your proposed) solution works when threaded. Also, for this example/project session variables are shared. But this should also apply to any other form of shared variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a possible solution, but not a very clean one. Creating a single `session_struct` in `main` and passing that around as an argument (by reference), or storing references/copies/shared pointers in all classes that needs access to the session data, is much cleaner.

What happens when multithreading comes into play is that you'd have to put a mutex around the shared data to prevent race conditions, where several threads access try to access the information at the same time. If you pass it around as an argument, that problem still exists, but you can sometimes avoid it by copying the structure so that each thread has a copy that it can update. Then merge the structures after all threads have completed. (Maybe refactor it into modifiable and constant parts to prevent some copying.)

Btw., there's no need to write `struct session_struct`. Just define it with `struct Session` and use as `Session`.

Comment: I have like one gazillion functions and event handlers where passing it around would be very annoying and vulnerable to bugs.

Comment: @nightcracker: then put a reference in every class that needs it.

Comment: Not class methods, plain old functions (I'm new to C / C++ so you're probably going to cry now :)). To be specific I have an array of event handlers functions for every event specified [here](http://mc.kev009.com/Protocol). Then I `recv()` one byte from the server which contains the event ID. And finally the main loop calls `event_handlers[event_id]()`.

Answer (score 0):

usage of global variables might have unsuspected side effects when your project grows large
You should create session_struct object in your main and use it everywhere.